# Getting error when click in my second post for the single page

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I am trying to open first post in single page, it's opening and when trying to open my second post in single page it;s showing "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"

Here is code

FrontendController

```
public function singlePost($slug)
{

    $post= Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();


    return view('single')->with('post', $post)


        ->with('title', $post->title)
        ->with('settings', Setting::first())
        ->with('categories', Category::take(4)->get());

}
```

single.blade.php

in that I am using same frontend controller for same page
@extends('layouts.frontend')

@section('content')

```
<div id="product-post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="heading-section">

                    <img src="{{$post->featured}}" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="single-blog" class="page-section first-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="product-item col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                <div class="product-content">
                                    <div class="product-title">
                                        <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
                                        <span class="subtitle">4 comments</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        {!! $post->content!!}

                                    </p>
                                </div>



                                <div class="leave-form">
                                    <form action="#" method="post" class="leave-comment">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="name col-md-4">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="email col-md-4">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="subject col-md-4">
                                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="text col-md-12">
                                                <textarea name="text" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="send">
                                            <button type="submit">Send</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




@endsection
```

Comment: Because the table has no record related to that slug.. Put if condition before you are getting value

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the value is coming from table or not before getting exact column value. In that case if your table return empty result you can redirect it to 404 page.

Please refer the code below :

```
public function singlePost($slug)
{

   $post= Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

   if($post) {
     return view('single')->with('post', $post)
       ->with('title', $post->title)
       ->with('settings', Setting::first())
       ->with('categories', Category::take(4)->get());
   } else {
      // You can redirect to 404 page
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you  , I have data  in column table id: 2,
         title: "Ultimate taste",
         featured: "uploads/posts/155236353572592.jpg",
         content: "<p>This is for health</p>",
         category_id: 2,
         slug: "ultimate-taste",
         deleted_at: null,
         created_at: "2019-03-12 04:05:35",
         updated_at: "2019-03-15 05:20:56",
       },
 this is the data in my table , and for single post it's working but for 2nd and another it not working

Comment: <h4><a href={{route('post.single', ['slug'=>$second_post->slug])}}">{{$second_post->title}}</a></h4>
                            <span>{{$second_post->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</span>
                        </div> here is code for 2nd single blog post

Comment: Please check the value is coming from table or not. Like this `print_r($post);`

Comment: I have checked it through, terrmial and also applied if else condition but still on same issue

Comment: "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object" it's showing this error

Comment: After the query add this one `print_r($post);die;`  aqnd check

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it's still showing that page not found error 404

Comment: Add your table structure with datas in question

Comment: Yes, I have done this, but still it's showing the same